# Z-index Issue with navigation bar

Tags: html, css

http://preview.spirecms.com/tpiswim.com/

The drop down navigation menu goes behind the slideshow and sidebar survey. It's probably a z-index issue, but I can't figure out how to fix it.

Thanks for your expertise!

Comment: Hi Rasta, please include a minimal, complete demo of your code issue in the question itself, rather than linking to an external site.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code can solve the problem :

```
#top-wrap {
    background: transparent;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: True, just edited my answer thanks :)

Comment: Thank you! Another z-index issue bites the dust!